# Runtime Error Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available in ionic 3.20

Tags: ionic3

cordova is installed. I am trying to use NativeGeocoder
this is my code that generates an error.

```
    this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(52.5072095, 13.1452818)
      .then((result: NativeGeocoderReverseResult) => {
            let country = this.toaster.create({
            message: result.countryName,
            duration: 4000
          });
          country.present();
      });
```

[image: screenshot of error]

Answer (score 0):

you need to test this code on actual device. this error will be removed then. or you can put a simple check about is cordova available. Normally, when testing a code in browser using ionic serve, cordova is not available.

Answer (score 0):

After the comment from  about calling native plugins before platform.ready I rechecked my code and all was correctly done BUT looks like the statusBar and appVersion plugins does not behave correctly when there is no cordova.js. While other plugins show a warning like:

Native: tried calling PluginName.prepare, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

statusBar and appVersion throw the error from my question. I wrapped them in a if(this.platform.is("cordova")) and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is native plugin, and as per your code you need to test your code/app in mobile application first. Your error definitely done .
Cordova not applicable for browser side. that's a main reason for your error.
Just compile your app for android/ios platform.

Kindly do same and revert us if still your issue not resolved.